# How to Remove Unwanted Zeors From Decimal Numbers In Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In My Crystal Report, I have three type of decimal numbers.

```
 1) 11.00 , 2.00

 2) 2.50, 1.30

 3) 11.75, 2.25
```

I need to format those 3 types as following

```
 1) 11, 2

 2) 2.5, 1.3

 3) 11.75, 2.25
```

That means I want to remove unwanted zeros from my decimal numbers. How can do it?

Comment: could you please include the code that you used to generate the report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- right click the field on the report canvas
- select format field
- select number tab
- select custom style
- select customize
- Next to decimal select the X-2 box and enter the following formula

  ```
  numbervar dec := 9; 
  numbervar i;
  numbervar j := dec + 1;
  numbervar x;

  for i := 1 to j do (
  if val(right(totext(currentfieldvalue,j,""),i)) = 0 then
  x := j  - i);
  x
  ```

below that select the X-2 button next to rounding and enter this formula

```
numbervar dec;
```

Comment: This thing works great but How do I apply this to the (formula) if that (formula) being used inside another Text formula?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
if ".0" IN ToText({ABC.ABC})
then 
Replace(Replace (ToText({ABC.ABC}), ".0","" ),"0","")
else 
Replace (ToText({ABC.ABC}), "0","" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Function with this code:

```
Function (NumberVar nNumber)
    Local StringVar sNumber := ToText(nNumber, 5); // 5 digits after floating point

    sNumber := Replace(sNumber, "0", " "); // replacing 0 to whitespaces so that TrimRight will work
    sNumber := TrimRight(sNumber);
    sNumber := Replace(sNumber, " ", "0"); // replacing whitespaces back to 0

    // Remove . at the end if the number was an integer
    If Right(sNumber, 1) = "." Then
        sNumber := Left(sNumber, Length(sNumber)-1);

    sNumber;
```